# Using remote sqlite DB with Android App

Tags: android, database, sqlite, remote-access

I am trying to sync a local sqlite DB with a remote sqlite DB, running on my Banana Pi. My objective hereby is to be able to update the DB on my Pi, the App checks by each launch, if some datasets have changed and if so it updates the Data.

Creating a local sqlite DB is no Problem but I just can't find anything to connecting Android with a remote DB, except for mySQL. Since the Pi can't handle mySQL that good I have to stick with sqlite.

So has someone got an Idea how to achieve my plan, or are mySQL and sqlite so similar that I could use almost the same commands.

I have got experience with PHP and mySQL just as side note.

Comment: Can the Pi act as a WebService provider? If so, you're good to go. Write your WebServices and use them.

Comment: The Pi is like a mini server, I just don't know how to write the code.

Comment: As far as I know, Pi runs a Linux. So, a LAMP (Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP/Perl/Python) solution might work.

Comment: Well I read that MySQL works, but not that good since it is pretty CPU-intensive

Comment: As far as the Android part goes (client of the service) check [this](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)